# How to change the value of variable inside a class using another class in java?

Tags: java, variables, netbeans, passwords

I have here [user login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P07uT.png) and [change password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEikI.png), now in change password class button save action event  I have code like this

```
 if(txtCurrentPassword.getText().equals(LoginFrm.defaultPassword) &&
           txtNewPassword.getText().equals(txtConfirmPassword.getText())){
           // CODE SHOULD BE HERE TO PASS THE NEW PASSWORD VALUES  TO USER LOGIN FORM IF THE CONDITION IS TRUE
           JLabel message = new JLabel("You are successfully changed your password");
           message.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
   }
```

Now as you can see at the condition above there is a public static variable called defaultPassword,this
variable is at the User login class, and this  variable has a String value the default password of the user. Now how to change the value of variable defaultPassword inside a class user login using changePassword class ?
Any suggestion would help or tell me if there's something to modify in this idea?Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Given that defaultPassword is a publicly accessible static field in the LoginFrm class, you can directly update its reference to the new password String. The below snippet should work.

```
if(txtCurrentPassword.getText().equals(LoginFrm.defaultPassword) &&
       txtNewPassword.getText().equals(txtConfirmPassword.getText())){
       LoginFrm.defaultPassword = txtNewPassword.getText();
       JLabel message = new JLabel("You are successfully changed your password");
       message.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
}
```

Comment: I already put that code but it doesn't work :)

Answer (score -1):

If it's a public static variable, you should be able to access it through ClassName.variableName. However, this is not necessarily best practice. It may be wise to privatize that variable and create methods for getting/setting it.

Comment: private String currentPassword = "1234";
    
    public String getNewPassword(){
       return currentPassword;
    }
    
    public void setNewPassword(String newPassword){
       this.currentPassword = newPassword;
    }   This getter  and setter method are inside LoginFrm class